# Xamarin project does not support framework '.netframework version=v4.0'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, .net-framework-version

I have an xamarin old code base (created in 2014), when i tried to load in visual studio for mac, It gives the following error.

```
project does not support framework '.netframework version=v4.0'
```

When i searched to download .netframework 4 (for mac) separately, i could not find any files.

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is your project PCL based?

Comment: What type of project is it? Xamarin.iOS|Mac|Android, PCL, etc...? (Project type GUID?)

Comment: Its a xamarin.iOS project not an PCL based project

Comment: You have only one project, no business project?

Comment: Found [this question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76829/opening-project-built-under-old-xamarin-in-new-version-of-xamarin) in the Xamarin forums that looks similar to your issue. The [accepted answer](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/220520/#Comment_220520) is to remove `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` from the affected csproj files.

Comment: @Andrew You should post this as an answer. It works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution  is to remove `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` from the `.csproj` files that are throwing the error.